# Работа с картинками-ссылками вместо текстовых ссылок

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый вечер!
Исходные данные: каталог товаров, каждый товар которого на странице отображается друг под другом. Есть возможность по ссылке "Раскрыть все" (или "Скрыть все", значение меняется) раскрыть все товары, а также раскрыть/скрыть каждый товар по отдельности ( с помощью текстовых ссылок [+] и [-] соответственно).
Собственно код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showinfo').click(function() { //при клике на .showinfo скрываем/раскрываем блок с инфой  
    $(this).text($(this).text()=='[-]' ? '[+]' : '[-]');  
    $(this).parent().find('.productinfo').toggle('slow');
    return false;   });
    $('#show-all').click(function() { //при клике на #show-all раскрываем все блоки, меняем тексты кнопок 
    if ($('#show-all').text()=='Раскрыть все')
    {$('.productinfo').show('slow');}   
    if ($('#show-all').text()=='Скрыть все')
    {$('.productinfo').hide('slow');}   
    $(this).text($(this).text()=='Скрыть все' ? 'Раскрыть все' : 'Скрыть все');
    if ($('#show-all').text()=='Скрыть все') {$('.showinfo').text('[-]');} 
    else {$('.showinfo').text('[+]');}  
    return false;   });
    }); </script>
```

Проблема в следующем. Как сделать так чтобы вместо текстовых ссылок ( [+] и [-] ) вставить соответствующие картинки, да так чтобы функционал не изменился (картинки бы по клику менялись и т.д.)
Буду благодарен за любой помощь. Подскажите хоть в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Я бы вообще закрыл вопрос сразу, уже отвечали на подобное!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[-] и [+] в коде видите? Вместо этих значков пишите код ваших картинок.

Comment: Не совсем понял Вас.
Например у меня картинка с адресом <img src="/plus.png">. Как мне привязать эту картинку к ссылке с классом ".showinfo". Одно дело через свойство .text() просто менять текст, а как в таком случае быть?

Comment: В вашем коде text(...) меняйте на html(...), чтобы теги работали, вместо `[+]` пишите `<img src="/plus.png">`, вместо `[-]` - `<img src="/minus.png">`.

Comment: @ling, text еще на html заменить ;) А то так и будет кодом.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!
Поменял `.text` на `.html`, но ругается (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`) на эту строчку:

    if ($('#show-all').text()=='Скрыть все') {$('.showinfo').html("<img src="/img/bullet_toggle_minus.png">");} 

А ещё как быть в случае, когда я сравниваю 

    $(this).text($(this).text()=='[-]' ? '[+]' : '[-]');  

так?

    $(this).text($(this).html()=='<img src="/img/bullet_toggle_minus.png">' ? '<img src="/img/bullet_toggle_plus.png">' : '<img src="/img/bullet_toggle_minus.png">');

Comment: Ругается из-за кавычек. Вы их либо экранируйте, либо замените одинарными.  
Сравнивать можно по `$(this).find('img').attr('src')` - искать там вхождение plus или minus.

Answer (score 1):

А не проще ли ссылке с классом  "`.showinfo`" прописать в css: `display:inline-block` и `background:url(/plus.png)`, и при клике на нее, отслеживая текущее состояние, менять `background-position`?